# Probabilities of many independent events

Tags: probability

> If $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_m$ are independent and $\mathbb{P}(A_i)=p$ for
>   $i=1,\dots,m$, find the probability that:
>
> - none of the $A_i$ occur,
> - an even number of the $A_i$ occur.

For the first question, I would say the required probability is:
$$
1 - \mathbb{P}(\cup_i A_i) = 1- \mathbb{P}(\cap_i A_i^c) = 1 - \prod_{i=1}^m (1-p) = 1 - (1-p)^m.
$$
The independence requirement is what allows to expand:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\cap_i A_i^c) = \prod_i\mathbb{P}(A_i^c).
$$

As for the second point, I was thinking for example that the case that exactly 2 events out of $m$ occur is:
$$
{m \choose 2}p^2(1-p)^{m-2},
$$
the case that exactly four events occur is:
$$
{m\choose 4}p^4(1-p)^{m-4},
$$
and so on, and then we would have to sum over all the even numbers less or equal than $m$.

I am not sure of my answers though.

Comment: At a) isn´t it just $(1-p)^m$? $m$ of $m$ (all) events do not occur.

Comment: I guess you are right, the correct inequality would just be: $(\cup_i A_i)^c = \cap_i A_i^c$.

Comment: I would say $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^m A_i^c=\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^m A_i^c$. Without the brackets at the left-hand side.

Comment: Maybe you meant: $\cup_i A_i=\cap_i A_i^c$?

Comment: Not really. I don´t say that your equation is false, but I´m not sure. What is your argument for your equation?

Comment: Perhaps this will help for second question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3054430/probability-that-we-choose-even-edges-for-a-vertex?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: My argument is drawing a Venn diagram for the case $m=2$. Now I see that my second comment is wrong, but not the first. The second should have been... the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first answer is incorrect. The probability that none of the events occur is just
$$\mathbb{P}(\cap_{i}A_{i}^{c})=(1-p)^{m}$$
Your second answer is correct. To make this rigorous, note that whether $m=2k$ ($m$ is even) or $m=2k+1$ ($m$ is odd), the largest even integer less than or equal to $m$ is $2k$ so we could write the desired probability as 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor{m/2}\rfloor}\binom{m}{2k}p^{2k}(1-p)^{m-2k}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to the first question is wrong. Note that
$$
P(\bar{A_1}\bar{A_2}\dotsb\bar{A_n})=\prod_{i=1}^n P(\bar{A_i})=(1-p)^n
$$
by independence. Let $Y_i=I(A_i)$ be the indicator random variable that $A_i$ occurs. Then $Z=\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ is the number of events that occur and is the sum of $n$ i.i.d Bernoulli random variables with probability of success $p$. It follows that $Z\sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$.

We can also check this via pgf computations. In particular the probability generating function of $Z$ is 
$$
\sum_{k\geq 0}P(Z=k)t^k=Et^Z\stackrel{\star}{=}\prod_{i=1}^n Et^{Y_i}=\prod_{i=1}^n(1-p+pt)=(1-p+pt)^n
$$ 
as expected where in $\star$ we used independence.

Since $Z\sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$, the required probability for the second question is 
$$
\sum_{k=0, \,k\,\text{even}}^nP(Z=k)=\sum_{k=0, \,k\,\text{even}}^n\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p^{n-k}.
$$